# How does the Android Downloadmanager work?

Tags: android, request, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download a file to the files-folder of the app

/data/user/0/app-name/files/

If I enqueue the download, the app crashes and I don't know why.
Trying setDestinationUri() AND setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() both won't work.

What is the big mistake?

```
DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://testpage.com/download.php");

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

//File fileDl = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/");
String dFolder = getFilesDir().toString();

request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + dFolder + "/"));
//request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(fileDl + "/", "epaper.pdf");

downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

I know some of you can see the misunderstanding, but as a Newbie I'm blind :-)

Can anybody help?

Thx,
Chris

Comment: If you use setDestinationUri it should be an uri for a file. Not of a folder.

Comment: if you use setDestinationInExternalPublicDir then you should mention a public dir that already exists. You would mention a folder name. Not a full path to a folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it helped to understand the problem.
But my idea of this

request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/epaper.pdf"));

Ended the same way. As soon as I activate

downloadmanager.enqueue(request);

The app crashes. Anything else I have to note on this?

Comment: File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "epaper.pdf");  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);. But DownloadManager is verry picky about the uri. If getFilesDir() does not work then try getExternalFilesDir(null).

Comment: Thank you very much! Download now works and I leanred a little bit :-)